# How to place declaration of Javascript function properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've got a problem with declaration of JQuery function. Function works only if I place it in `$(document).ready()`
If the declaration is below ready() function, my function doesn't work.

My function:

```
   $('#me').click( function(){

       $('#content').load('me.php');
       return false;

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you will need to add all events ex. `.click(), .change()` inside of document.ready

because you can only add events to the element after its properly added to page and `$(document).ready()` will only execute jquery after entire html will load properly

Read: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 1):

You should add all event `click, change...etc`. after html load only. so you should write these events in  `$(document).ready()`

If you want your code should be cleaned and readable. you can try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#me').click(myFunction);
});

  function myFunction(){
       $('#content').load('me.php');
       return false;
        };
```